# Force flex item on a single line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the below example and I want to display the blue item text on a single line all the time no matter how much text I will have inside. (dynamic content) Basically I want the red item to get smaller in width when the blue item has more text.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thx

PS. Don't ask why I use flex here. I use it into a bigger example where I need it, this example is simplified.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}   
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `flex-shrink:0`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)</sup> on the blue part:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}   
.blue {
  background: blue;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue</div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue </div>
</div>
```

Or the old `white-space:nowrap`:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}   
.blue {
  background: blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue</div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue </div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to set `flex:1` to the red part. This will allow the content of the blue part to break into multiple lines when the red one can no more break:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  flex:1;
}   
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue</div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red red  red red red red red red </div>
  <div class="blue">blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue blue </div>
</div>
```